# Impressora fiscal via web é possível?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, aplicação-web, impressora

Estou implementando um sistema para emissão de nota fiscal com impressora fiscal em C#, porém gostaria saber se o mesmo é possível via web utilizando JavaScript HTML, CSS etc.

Como eu faria isso? Através de quais ferramentas e recursos?

Comment: Como você mensionou "impressora fiscal", suponho que esteja falando de ECF (Emissor de Cupom Fiscal). Nesse caso não é possível pois a homologação para este tipo de emissão é muito rígida (ex: gerar chave md5 do executável, dll, do sofware emissor). Para cupom Eletrônico (NFC-e - que está substituido em grande parte do Brasil o ECF) talvez seja possível já que existe projetos de emissão da NF-e via WEB, a diferença é o tipo da impressora. Veja o projeto [Nota Fiscal Eletrônica em PHP](http://www.nfephp.org/), boa sorte. @asura-khan

Comment: Ahh entendo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Eu não queria um passo a passo, na verdade eu queria essa solução que você me passou, para eu dar procedimento a minha pesquisa. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for usar uma impressora fiscal mesmo para fins fiscais, esqueça, a própria legislação impede o uso através de navegadores. Não de forma explícita mas pelos requisitos para homologação do software.

Mesmo que seja uma impressora não fiscal ou seja usada para fins não fiscais ainda tem o problema de que a impressora só pode ser acessada pelo navegador. Ele tem controle sobre como mandar informações para a impressora. Mesmo assim, ainda tem o limite do sistema operacional.

Muitas vezes estas impressoras já são problemáticas para acessar de um aplicação *desktop* dadas as limitações do sistema operacional. Uma solução comum é escrever direto na porta.

Imagine a dificuldade de passar por isto com as limitações extras que o navegador impõe. Você pode tentar criar uma página, provavelmente sem HTML, e mandar imprimir e ver se consegue algum resultado. Mas duvido que dê certo. Fora isto pode pedir suporte para o fabricante mas acho que ele responderá o mesmo que estou respondendo aqui.

Fora isto é possível criar um aplicativo que acesse a impressora para o usuário acessar. Eventualmente ele pode se comunicar com o navegador mas acho que esta solução costuma ser ruim. Na maioria das vezes é mais fácil fazer uma aplicação *desktop* que resolva todo o problema. Aplicações *web* não resolvem todos os problemas, [um martelo não trabalha bem com um parafuso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

[image: Martelo com parafuso]

Até o momento desconheço uma forma de resolver este problema de outra forma. E é algo que já procurei bastante.

E dependendo do que seja a definição de uma página HTML normal também não vai conseguir imprimir neste tipo de impressora mesmo que tenha acesso direto a ela. Essas impressoras não costumam ser capazes de imprimir coisas sofisticadas como uma página HTML.

Provavelmente não é o que você quer mas é possível fazer o trabalho de impressão no servidor sem envolver HTML na impressão em si, aí você tem controle total como se fosse uma aplicação *desktop*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).